# MediaPlayer looping when BroadcastReceiver receives broadcast from AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-mediaplayer, alarmmanager

In my app, clicking the start button selects a random time from 5 seconds to 5 minutes and sets an AlarmManager to wait until that random time is met and then a sound is played. Then once the sound is played, if the stop button has not yet been pressed, the AlarmManager is again set to wait for a new random amount of time. My issue is that once the time is up the first time the sounds just plays like 15 times at once so I have to clear the cache of the app to make it stop.

Here is the code for the buttons and the AlarmManager:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu_layout);

    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    startButton.setText("START");
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if (!stop)
            {
                setAlarm(MainMenu.this);
            }//end while
        }//end onClick

    });//end startButton onClickListener

    Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    stopButton.setText("STOP");
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            stop = true;
        }//end onClick

    });//end stopButton onClickListener

}//end onCreate

public static void setAlarm(Context passedContext)
{
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(passedContext, AlarmReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) passedContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Random random = new Random();
    long time = random.nextInt(300000) + 5000; //random number from 5000 ms 
                                             //to 300000 ms (5 sec to 5 min)
    Toast.makeText(passedContext, "random: " + time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(passedContext, 1,
        intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
}//end setAlarm
```

Here is the code for the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.shots);
    player.start();

    if (MainMenu.stop == false)
        MainMenu.setAlarm(context);
}//end onReceive
```

I have no idea why it keeps getting back into the code to start the sound enough to play it on top of other instances and I could really use the help. It is as if the AlarmManager just keeps broadcasting or something.

UPDATE: 
After a bit of testing I noticed that it only plays multiple instances of the sound on top of each other when it is the first time the start button has been pressed once the app is opened. Every time the start button is pressed afterward it plays as it should. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Uri alert = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, alert);
        mp.setVolume(10, 10);
        mp.start();
         mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
         mp.release();

         }
         });
```

Try this one

Comment: That did nothing. I am pretty sure it has nothing to do with the way that the media is actually being played / setup.

Comment: when i did it is working properly .i just removed   if (MainMenu.stop == false)
        MainMenu.setAlarm(context); these two linesfrom your code n removed flag_update current

Comment: Ok that makes it play right the first time, but it does not call the method to set another random time again. I did it this way so the random number could continually change. Otherwise I would have used a repeating AlarmManager.

Answer (score 0):

add to your receiver :

```
player.setLooping(false);
```

Comment: Ok I gave that a shot and it did not resolve the issue. When I say it is looping I mean it sounds like it is playing the sound 10 times at once.

Comment: Ok i understand now.. try to remove " PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT" from alarmManager.set(...)

Comment: That did not work. I set that value to zero and it still plays like 15 instances of the song on top of each other.

Comment: Any other ideas? I appreciate the help.

Comment: after seeing your update and trying your code on my emulator (just setAlarm ), i'm confused more, because the first time i click in the button it plays the song (only a small part, and there's no repeating here) the next time i click the song plays normal but in the 2 cases the song starts immediately.